# Query regarding admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Can someone please explain, what does (resource, userKey) represents in AdminDirectory.Users.update(**resource, userKey**). I believe **userKey** represents primary email id.(Correct me if im wrong). But i have no idea what resource is.. I am new to Google App script

Thanks in Adavacne

Answer (score 0):

`userKey` - Identifies the user in the API request. The value can be the user's primary email address, alias email address, or unique user ID. For the resource you can check this [page.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource-representations)

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But i want to know how it works in above code- I have tried AdminDirectory.Users.update(password, email@domainname). But it didnt work. Can you please help me.

Comment: Finally it worked..I have modified my code as below-                                var user = 'user_email id@domain.com'                                               var resource = {
             "password": 'aaa1213',
              "changePasswordAtNextLogin": 'true'
            }
  AdminDirectory.Users.update(resource,user);

Comment: then that's great :)